# what happened to my OEM key after windows 10 home upgrade from windows 7 home premium?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-activation, oem, samsung-laptop

I upgrade from windows 7 home premium to windows 10 home, after the upgrade the product id changed and doesn't include OEM in the key anymore. even after running `SLMGR /dlv` in CMD
it brings the product key channel as Retail so what happened to my OEM?,

Side Note:

I didn't use KMS when I done fresh install for windows 10 I choose I don't have key and it automatically it activated.

This is greet and all but is my motherboard OEM key overwritten?, My Laptop is `Samsung 300v5A` from 2012 shipped with windows 7 home premium and it was an OEM key.

Note:

I upgraded using windows media creation tool.

my main question is my motherboard OEM key overwritten by windows 10 fresh install?

Comment: You have upgraded with a Retail License. Make sure you are the legal owner of the retail license.

Comment: So that is all that happened and now your license is Retail.

Comment: Most likely yes.  Licensing is held in the Microsoft Licensing Server.

Comment: “my main question is my motherboard OEM key overwritten by windows 10 fresh install?” - This absolutely positively definitely didn’t happen. Windows 7 keys are not store in the ACPI table (if your unfamiliar with that term look it up). However, it’s a know fact when you upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7, a generic Windows 10 key is used (one for Home and one for Professional) for the digital entitlement activation. The Windows 7 key still exists it was “over written”. Your Windows 7 key is printed on the COA sticker on your device.  Why exactly are you looking for it?

Comment: @Mohab13 - Windows 11 can be activated by the digital entitlement your hardware has for Windows 10. When you go to reinstall Windows 11 or Windows 10 you would skip the step of providing a Windows key.  This is all documented by 6 years of Windows 10 questions on the subject. Unfortunately you have received an comment  that isn’t factual accurate. I should clarify you don’t actually specify you installed a Retail installation of Windows 10 Home. In order to do that it would have been required to enter a product key otherwise you would have been upgraded to a OEM copy of Windows 10

Comment: It’s impossible for a OEM license to turn into a Retail key without using and entering a retail key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you installed Windows 10 (upgrading from Windows 7) with a Retail License, it replaced your OEM license with a Retail License.

Now the license is held in the Microsoft Licensing Server.

You can reinstall Windows, change the main drive, and the license will still hold.

Since this was a Windows 7 machine originally, it is likely too old to run Windows 11.  Run the Microsoft PC Health Check to see.